# Bringing a subview to the front of a UIVisualEffect view?

Tags: swift, subview, uivisualeffectview

I've got a view at the top/bottom of my screen that's a blurred view. Ontop of the view I'm wanting to show my buttons unblurred, so I would assume the buttons need to be ontop of the blurred view.

in viewDidLoad I'm running this code :

```
if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() {
    self.blurOutletTop.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    self.blueOutletBot.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    let blurEffectView2 = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    //always fill the view
    blurEffectView.frame = blurOutletTop.frame //self.view.bounds
    blurEffectView2.frame = blueOutletBot.frame
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]



    self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView2)

    logoOutlet.bringSubview(toFront: self.view) //This is where my issue is


} else {
    blurOutletTop.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    blueOutletBot.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

So this makes the two views I have top/bottom blurry. Where I'm running into an issue is where I'm trying to have my logoOutlet infront of the blurred view so it doesn't get blurred. I've tried brining it to the front of the blurrEffectView, the blurOutletTop view, and self.view and everything has the same effect.

I wouldn't assume a button that is not behind a blur view would get effected by the blur. How do I get this to work? I'm also unable to even press the buttons that are now under the view so bringing it to the front doesn't seem to be working. (logoOutlet is an outlet for a button).

edit: I also have tried setting the outlet's zPosition to 9999, no change.